# How i can build a Column Chart inside Power App for my sharepoint list

Tags: power-automate, powerapp, powerapps-canvas

I have the following sharepoint list:-

[image]

as shown it shows an Engineer's name and the number of green and red points each engineer got.

so I want to build a Power App canvas that shows a column chart >> where the column chart should show 2 columns (Green & Red) for each engineer?

Is this Possible, something as follow:-

[image]

Regards

Now I tried the following, where I created a Column chart with the number of series =2 as follow:-

[image]

but i can not get the engineer name inside the Label:-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you're selecting **{Name}** for your **Labels** of the Graph. I think, {Name} is empty in your SPO list and that's why not seeing values in the graph. You need to select the internal name of the **[Engineer]** column. Labels are automatically shown if selected the correct column.

### SharePoint List

Note: [Title] column of the list renamed as [Engineer]

[image]

### Power Apps Graph

[image]

[image]

I would recommend this [YouTube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b8iz1ar1I4E)